# CM Theme not running or not showing up in theme chooser (Settings>Themes)

Tags: android, android-studio, themes, cyanogenmod, android-studio-2.1

I am new to creating themes and I'm running CM13, I'm trying to create CM theme. I am just trying to start with a simple theme that changes the wallpaper and lockscreen image. I am using Android Studio. I tried using the template provided by cyanogenmod and I tried to start from scratch. Both would run but would not install properly. I can't seem to get them to show up in the theme chooser under Settings>Theme. I am running nightlies for lg g3 with no other modifications.

My android manifest:

```html
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.georgialways.thefluxroom">

    <uses-feature android:name="org.cyanogenmod.theme" />

    <meta-data android:name="org.cyanogenmod.theme.name" android:value="TheFluxRoom" />
    <meta-data android:name="org.cyanogenmod.theme.author" android:value="georgialways" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    </application>

</manifest>
```

My gradle:

```html
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.georgialways.thefluxroom"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
}
```

My phone Catlog during run
[here](http://imgur.com/a/r3VSa)

Edit:
I found a [theme that I can run](https://github.com/gabrielelucci/greyscale-cmte) to my phone and it shows up under themes but I still don't understand why the one from Gabriel will run but the one from Cyanogenmod's github won't run (or at least show up)